# How to insert video source in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I put a video in my html code and when I run the website it is not showing. I checked my code and everything is fine with it.

I tried different browsers and players, i tried with different videos

```
 <! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
    photos

    </title>
        <link href="CSS/journalstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body style="background-image: url(images/bricks.jpg)">
        <div class="row">

             <img src="images/lidia.png" style="width: 120px; height: 40px;" class="logo">

            <div class="row-right">

         <a href="register.html">Register</a>
         <a href="about.html">About me</a>
         <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
         <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          <a href="journals.html">Home</a> 
            <br>
            <br>

            </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Photos and Media</h1>
        <p> Here are my 3 Artefacts</p>
        <br> <br>

        <br>
        <h3>Artefact 1</h3>
        <br>
    <img src="images/MOSHED-2018-11-10-12-28-30.gif" style="width:300px;heigh:200px;">
        <br>
    <h3>Artefact 2</h3>
        <br>

        <br>
        <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
        <source src="media/Artefact2.mov" type="video/.mov">
        </video>
        <br>

       <h3>Artefact 3</h3>




    </body>

</html>
```

I expect to see the video on the website

Comment: Maybe `type="video/.mov"` is not correct. It should be `video/quicktime` (See http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/)

Comment: What happens when you try to load the video directly in the browser? e.g. try visiting www.yourwebsite.com/media/Artefact2.mov

Answer (score 8):

I would upload to YouTube and use their embedding. That's always easier in my opinion and will increase the speed of your website.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5, there are 3 supported video formats: MP4, WebM, and Ogg.

Answer (score 2):

just change the file type to **"video/mov"**

```
<video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
 <source src="media/Artefact2.mov" type="video/mov">
</video>
```

You can refer to this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp for further queries